# custom ios tableview cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell, if the cell is clicked then the cell should be expanded and if not clicked then the cell should not be expanded.

There is also a custom view and if the cell is clicked, I want the height of the custom view to be increased and if the cell is not clicked then it should be a certain height.Below this code is set in cellForRowAt

```
 if TableView.rowHeight == 126 {

            cell.CustomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 20))

            return cell
        }
        else{

        }
```

But the code I set to change the height of the view is not working and I am not sure where to go from there

When the cell is not clicked this is how my custom View looks like:[image]

When the cell is clicked this is what the custom view looks like:[image]

As you can see my problem is when the cell is not clicked, the bottom of the View is a straight line but when the cell is clicked, the bottom is rounded. I want the View to also be rounded when the cell is not clicked.

Comment: are you calling `reloadData` in `didSelectRow`?

Comment: set the height constraint for the custom view and change it accordingly when expanding and shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

Call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` to force `tableView` to update heights

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // new row selected
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066537/is-there-any-way-refresh-cells-height-without-reload-reloadrow)

Comment: it updates the height of the cell, the only thing it doesn't do is update the height of the view. The view is set at a height of 300 and when it is clicked, the height remains 300 but when it is not clicked the height of the view is still 300

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below . Hope this is gonna help you .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: self)
        self.isExpanded = true
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        self.isExpanded = false
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.selectedIndex = IndexPath()
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Courtesy : @Jože Ws

Comment: I have updated my question to hopefully make my question a little clearer Thank you very much

Comment: the update of your question have turned into entirely different question ( although still not enough clear )  . so , next time form a clear question before  someone has invested his time on it . @juelizabeth

Comment: I'm sorry, you wasted your time